# how to automatically include characters in textbox

Tags: vb.net

how to automatically include alphabetic characters in a text box based on the selection from combo box in vb.net,leaving the other spaces for the user to enter .say the text box contains 8 characters (eg. 117CS227 ).the CS in text box must automatically include leaving the remaining first and last three spaces for the user to enter in the text box.this text should automatically include based on the selection from combo box.
eg say there are three selections from combo box (computers ,biology,maths) . if the user selects computers then the text box below the combo box must include cs in them and for biology and maths ,they should include bg and ms respectively in the text box.
(the text box and combo box are in the same form)

Comment: have you considered a masked edit? or you could add "CS" upon seeing the length was 3.

Comment: masked edit work for all selections

Comment: i need different characters to enter based on different selection. if the user selects computers from combo box then automatically the textbox must include cs

Comment: if he selects biology then it must include bs in them

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. In your example, the CS is in the middle of the text. Do you want VB to insert the CS in the middle, or does it get appended on the end of the user's input, or does it get put at the beginning and when does it get put there?

Comment: When and where is he choosing computer science or biology? is that a different combo box?

Comment: it must be included in the middle

Comment: combo box and text box are in the same form

Comment: when the user selects computer from the combobox ,then the text box below it must automatically include cs in them leaving the first and last 3 spaces for the user to enter

Comment: Try using two TextBoxes and a Label in the middle that holds the "CS" characters.

Comment: Why not capture the TextChanged event and check to see if the user has entered CS in the middle of the string?  If they haven't, add it.

Comment: this is a desktop voting application. everything must be automatically checked .